# dir /ta for displaying last-access times sometimes shows last-write times instead

Tags: cmd.exe, windows-11, timestamp, dir

On my Windows 11 22H2 system, I've verified that that last-access timestamps *are* maintained (`fsutil behavior query disableLastAccess`), and *in PowerShell* they can be retrieved.

However, with `cmd.exe`'s [`dir`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir) command, `/ta`, i.e. displaying files by their last-*access* time, *situationally* seems to behave the same as `/tw`, i.e. displaying them by their last-*write* time.

This only happens *sometimes*:

- It happens with *certain* files, but there appears to be nothing special about them (text files with only the `A` attribute set).
- When it does happen, File Explorer too shows the last-*write* timestamp instead (but PowerShell always shows the correct time stamp.

*I cannot reproduce this reliably*: the PowerShell test code below works as intended.

Is this related to timestamps getting *cached*? But, if so, why is PowerShell able to retrieve them? For affected files, the problem persists even after a couple of hours.

---

PowerShell test code, which does *not* exhibit the symptom.

```sh
# Create a test file.
1 > _test.txt

# Assign distinctive timestamps.
(Get-Item _test.txt).LastWriteTime = '1970-01-01'
(Get-Item _test.txt).LastAccessTime = '1970-01-01'

# Read the file, so as to update its last-access timestamp.
$null = Get-Content _test.txt

# List the file with its last-access timestamp.
cmd /c dir _test.txt /ta

# Do the same in PowerShell
Get-Item _test.txt | Select-Object Name, LastAccessTime
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be that there are multiple Last Access times. Really.

The Microsoft article
[fsutil behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-behavior)
says:

> One hour is the maximum amount of time that NTFS can defer updating Last Access Time on disk. If NTFS updates other file attributes such as Last Modify Time, and a Last Access Time update is pending, NTFS updates Last Access Time with the other updates without additional performance impact.

To reduce disk thrashing, Windows is supposed to keep the Last Access Time
in memory for one hour before being flushed out to disk,
in order to minimize disk I/O. So you already have two access times
and, depending on the API they use, different tools might report
either time in an inconsistent manner.

The question of last-access was investigated by Msuhanov in the article
[The (in)consistency of last access timestamps](https://dfir.ru/2018/12/16/the-inconsistency-of-last-access-timestamps/).

His results were not very encouraging :

- Disk write of the Last Access Time may happen after much longer time
  than one hour. In one case, it was only written out after 12 hours
  when Msuhanov gave up and turned off his computer.
  During this period, a program might get either the old or new time,
  depending on how/where it's getting it.
- Msuhanov also found out that there were *two Last Access Times*:
  One in a file record and another one in an index record ($I30).
  So, depending on the access API function, or the modify API function,
  one would be dealing with one or the other, with no guarantee of
  consistency.

So now we have *three last accessed times* in Windows !

My conclusion is that
the Last Access Time implementation in Windows is finicky and
unreliable. I don't know which of these time stamps are used
in `dir`, the memory one or the disk one.
It's possible that `dir` shows
the disk one, and this changes when Windows decides to write
the memory one to the disk.

I wouldn't recommend relying on the last accessed times to be correct.
It's not a reliable tool, and its implementation is weird.